# displaying different messages depending on parameters

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development. I have 10 different buttons and I want to display a toast for each one of them. The message is something like:

> "This is the button: " + numButton

Where numButton is a prop passed to the function. This is the function code:

```
public void displayMensaje(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(ActividadUno.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And this is the xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:text="churro"
        android:onClick="displayMensaje"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: What have you accomplished so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tried passing the parameters directly in the xml like: android:onClick="displayMensaje(param1, param2, param3)" and changing the function to: public void displayMensaje(View v, int p1, int p2, int p3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the `View` in `Button` and get the text of button.

Something like this:

```
public void displayMensaje(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;
    String title = button.getText();
    String message = "Test " + title;
    Toast.makeText(ActividadUno.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Edit:**
According to my understanding from your comment below, you have multiple buttons in your activity, and you want to display different values on clicking different buttons.

You can have a `Map` with keys as button titles and values as nutrition values.

Below is a general example of how you can achieve this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // Your Message Format
    private static final String MSG_FORMAT = "Item Name: %s\n"
            + "Fat: %s\n"
            + "Protein: %s\n"
            + "Calories: %s";

    // A Map to hold info of all items
    // Key = button title
    // Value = Array containing item info
    private Map<String, String[]> info = new HashMap();

    // Assuming you have 3 buttons in your activity
    private Button btnMilk;
    private Button btnEggs;
    private Button btnChicken;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        btnMilk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_milk);
        btnEggs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_eggs);
        btnChicken = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chicken);

        // 0 = Fat, 1 = Protein, 2 = Calories
        String[] milkInfo = new String[]{"12", "20", "125"};
        String[] eggsInfo = new String[]{"10", "50", "205"};
        String[] chickenInfo = new String[]{"50", "5", "500"};

        // load your Map with the data
        info.put(btnMilk.getText(), milkInfo);
        info.put(btnEggs.getText(), eggsInfo);
        info.put(btnChicken.getText(), chickenInfo);

    }

    public void displayMessage(View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;

        String title = button.getText();

        // Get item info from your Map
        String[] itemInfo = info.get(title);

        // Create message using the format and values from the array
        String message = String.format(MSG_FORMAT, title, itemInfo[0], itemInfo[1], itemInfo[2]);

        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This helped a lot and it´s in part what I wanted to acomplished. But I need to show more properties of each item, let´s say price for each one

Comment: @DexterNaru please explain in detail what you're exactly trying to accomplish? I don't know what exactly is your app or activity intended for.

Comment: I have a list of foods (eggs, milk, sausages, pork...) and i want to show nutritional information of each one  (fat, calories, proteins...) all with the same formatted message but varying the values